# bind character vector to list into dataframe

Tags: r, radix, tm, httr

I have a list of URLs and have extracted the content as follows:

```
library(httr)
link="http://www.workerspower.net/disposable-workers-the-real-price-of-sweat-shop-labor"
get.link=GET(link)
get.content=content(x2,as="text")
extract.content=str_extract_all(y2,"<p>(.*?)</p>")
```

This gives a "list of 1" with text. The length of each list is dependent on/varies with the URL.
I would like to bind the URL [link] with the content [extract.content] and transform it into a dataframe and then import that into a Corpus. 
My attempts fail, eg. this does not work because of the different row lengths:

```
all=data.frame(url.vec=c(link1,link2),text.vec=c(extract.content1,extract.content2))
```

Does anyone knows how to combine a character[vector] with a character[list]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using `XML` package. Then you should avoid using regular expression with html/xml documents. Use `xpath` instead. Here I create a small function that giving a link it create the corpus.

```
library(XML)
create.corpus <- function(link){
  doc <- htmlParse(link)
  parag <- xpathSApply(doc,'//p',xmlValue)
  library(tm)
  cc <- Corpus(VectorSource(parag))
  meta(cc,type='corpus','link') <- link
  cc
}
## call it 
cc <- create.corpus(link)
```

Inspecting the result:

```
 meta(cc,type='corpus')
# $create_date
# [1] "2014-01-03 17:40:50 GMT"
# 
# $creator
# [1] ""
# 
# $link
# [1] "http://www.workerspower.net/disposable-workers-the-real-price-of-sweat-shop-labor"

> cc
# A corpus with 36 text documents
```

Comment: Re: the advice to use a purpose-built parser rather than regex, everyone must view the accpeted answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags